# Reading Data Incrementally from S3 in Delta Format

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, delta-lake, incremental

I am working on a project where the data is stored in Delta format on Amazon S3, and I need to read this data incrementally. I am encountering challenges in implementing this, and I would appreciate guidance or insights from the community.
My current approach is to leverage transaction json metadata to look for any information regarding modified data on the location.

**What I've Tried:**

Delta Lake Documentation: I have referred to the Delta Lake documentation, to understand the best practices for reading data incrementally. However there is no concrete information regarding storing Delta format data on S3 or any other files sources although there is a lot about Delta SQL.

I expect to retrieve data incrementally from the S3 location in Delta format. Ideally, I would like suggestions on implementing this scenario.

**Environment Details:**

Delta Lake Version: 1.0.0
AWS SDK/Library Version: 1.11.375
Programming Language: Java
Spark Version - 3.1.2

Comment: What do you want to do: 1) Read a delta-table with say billion rows in chunks, and process each chunk, one time activity? OR 2) Keep monitoring a delta-table for changes, and process the newly added/updated rows say every 10 mins or 1 hour or...?

Comment: Keep monitoring a delta table for changes and process the newly added/updated rows... for a given interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

- [Change Data Feeds](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-change-data-feed.html) on Delta tables or

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (id INT, name STRING, age INT) TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)
```

and

```scala
val df = spark.read.format("delta")
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
  .option("startingVersion", 0)
  .table("student")
```

- Spark [Structured Streaming](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html)

```scala
val df = spark.readStream.format("delta")
  .load("/tmp/delta/events")

import io.delta.implicits._
val df = spark.readStream.delta("/tmp/delta/events")
```